# Can we get guidance/rules how to decide between 3 options of renting/buying/mortgaging a residence to live in

Tags: mortgage, rental-property, purchase

I hope my title of this question won't get me into trouble on this list.

My landlord sold the apartment we live in. Due to our circumstance, we can

1. Rent somewhere else and invest the cash in an index fund
2. We can buy a home in cash
3. We can put a down payment and get a mortgage

I realize that the answer can be based on our numbers, mortgage rates and tax bracket, but are there some rules we can get that can help us work out which make most sense?

Do we need to speak with someone for this? If so, which profession is best? investment advisor? acountant, tax lawyer? We don't have much time to run around. Best if those on the list can share their wisdom.

ty

Comment: So, you have enough cash to buy a house but are renting an apartment? If you got a mortgage, would you buy a bigger house, using all of your cash for a down payment? Not judging, just making sure I understand the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough cash that all three options are available to you, then I think you are better off asking what would make you happy rather than trying to optimize your wealth generation.

Would you rather rent or own?  Some people don't want to deal with the hassles of maintaining a home and others want the freedom to do what they want with their home.  Buying a condo is a compromise between these two.

For taking a mortgage versus paying in cash, some people enjoy owning their home outright (and don't want to worry about making the monthly mortgage payment) and others want to maximize their investment portfolio.  No right answer here.  Though instead of considering the extremes, consider how much of a down payment you want to put down.  This is an easy dial to adjust based on your personal preferences.